# Direction of facing while doing Sashtang Namaskar?

Tags: belief, worship

Which direction should a prostrated body face while doing sashtanga pranam to a diety/guru?

My understanding was that the deity is in front of a devotee and while doing sashtanga pranam, the prostrated devotees hands are pointing towards the deity. However, I have noticed in the Shiva temples in Tiruvannamalai, devotees prostrate sideways. The position is such that the diety is looking at the prostrated devotees left side of the torso. I cannot provide a photo as photography was prohibited. What could be the significance of prostrating sideways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the **Narayani tantram** as found in **Sarvollāsatantram**, 37-th Ulhassa:

> **नारायणीतंत्रे**--
> स्ववामे प्रणमेद्विष्णुं दक्षिणे गौरीशङ्करम्‌ ।
> गुरुं नमेत्‌ सम्मुखतो नान्यथा निष्फलं भवेत्‌॥ १९ ॥

> Perform the *Namaskarm* from your left to the Vishnu; from the right to Gauri and Shiva. From the front to a Guru, otherwise the *Namaskar* becomes fruit-less.

So as per this verse, if its vishnu one must perform *namaskar* from the left, for Shiva and Gauri from the right and guru from the front.

So in a Shiva Temple, if you are performing the *Namaskarm (pranam)* from your right side, the deity looks towards the left side of your body.